# Visibility changes worked on CoordinatorLayout but now they don't when changing to Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I implemented a progressbar visibility change from visible to invisible when some stuff finishes loading. It worked OK when parent view was a Coordinator Layout. Now I switched it to Constraint Layout and suddenly it doesn't work anymore.

This change is done programatically via an interface that listens to clicks. When a click is done inside a fragment, the callback sets the visibility off/on from within the activity. It worked fine, but now it doesn't.

The code is basically this: in my fragment `interface?.progressBarOff()` and in my activity

```
override fun progressBarOff() {
    progressbar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE // this line is getting called. so no problems with the interface
}
```

The `progressBarOn()` method is analogous to this one.

I tried:

1. runOnUiThread does nothing
2. Visibility changes DO WORK inside `onCreate` from my activity. But when the visibility is changed from the interface it's being called but just does nothing. If I set the visibility to `VISIBLE` inside `onCreate` it stays visible but can't change it.
3. `view.visibility = ConstraintLayout.VISIBLE` not working as well.
4. `view.visibility = View.GONE` not working as well.

I looked online for answers on why it's not working and some say that it's about `Groups` but I haven't used groups yet.

**MAIN_ACTIVITY.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blackBackground"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
    app:motionDebug="SHOW_ALL">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/player_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/player_background" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/TransparentActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/BlackActionBarPopUp" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/player_background"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <ProgressBar // THIS PROGRESS BAR
        android:id="@+id/main_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar_background"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navbar_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navbar_colors"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Comment: make sure you don't put `progressbar` View in any `ConstraintLayout Group` it will be break visibility

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I have no ussage of my progress bar in my code except for the interfaces

Comment: Post your xml layout

Comment: Done, please check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

As I'm using a Motion Layout I had to resort to using another Transition to achieve this effect.

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/progressbarOn">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/main_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/progressbarOff">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/main_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</ConstraintSet>

<Transition
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/progressbarOff"
    app:constraintSetStart="@id/progressbarOn"
    app:duration="0" />
```

And whenever I want to set the progressbar on or off I just type:

```
view.setTransition(R.id.progressbar)
view.transitionToStart() // sets visibility ON

view.setTransition(R.id.progressbar)
view.transitionToEnd() // sets visibility OFF
```

This hasn't brought up any error or any other bugs regarding my current animations.